# need help in c# game code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a tower defense game in unity, but I am stuck. I want my gun or turret to face the enemies until they're out of range, but after every 0.5 sec, it updates and faces another enemy within its range, despite the first enemy also being within range.

Here is my code:

```
void Start () 
{
    InvokeRepeating("UpdateTarget", 0f , 0.5f );
}   

void UpdateTarget()
{
    GameObject[] enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(enemyTag);
    float shortestDistance = Mathf.Infinity;
    GameObject nearestEnemy = null;

    foreach (GameObject enemy in enemies)
    {
        float distanceToEnemy = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemy.transform.position);
        if (distanceToEnemy < shortestDistance)
        {
            shortestDistance = distanceToEnemy;
            nearestEnemy = enemy;
        }
    }

    if (nearestEnemy != null && shortestDistance <= range)
    {
        target = nearestEnemy.transform;          
    }
    else 
    { 
        target = null; 
    }        
}
```

Comment: Maybe at the beginning you should check if there's already an active target, and if so, don't change it. Like: `if (target != null && Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) <= range) return;` (note: I don't know Unity, so this may not be correct code, but you get the idea...)

Comment: Yeah it sounds like they don't want it to change targets constantly, so maintaining an "active target" variable would be a good approach. Also, I highly recommend adding a box collider enclosing the turret's range, and use that to limit the number of enemies you have to search through. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/colliders-triggers might be of interest. Unity has powerful spacial indexing functionality built in so it's silly not to leverage that. I woudn't be surprised if there's even a built-in "nearest neighbor" algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You have to include a test in UpdateTarget, which should first check, if nearestEnemy is still in the range and in that case exit the function, otherwise search for a new target.

***Logic should look something like this:***

```
//keep old target?
if(nearestEnemy != null)
{
  //calculate distance of current target here..
  if(distance <= range)
     return; //keep this enemy as target
}
//here comes your code for finding a new target...
```

Comment: If you have an enemy close, then it becomes the nearestEnemy, good. You shoot at it, it stops moving (for any reason). Another enemy pass it by and come closer at you, it will never be the nearest enemy since the first one is still register.

Answer (score 1):

GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag has more impact on performance, i would suggest you create a circle collider 2d and set it to trigger, and when OnTriggerEnter2D is called you can fetch the enemy and raise a flag so that other enemies won't be triggered after that, when OnTriggerExit2D is called on that enemy you can start looking for another enemy or choose one of the enemies that are still in that colliders radius.

```
private bool _foundEnemy;
private Enemy _currentEnemy;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (_foundEnemy) return;

    _currentEnemy = collision.GetComponent<Enemy>();
    // your code here
    _foundEnemy = true;
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(_currentEnemy!=null && collision.GetComponent<Enemy>() == _currentEnemy)
        _foundEnemy = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You weren't completely clear on what behavior you want to achieve, but it seems to be to lock to a target until it's dead, and only then switch to another target. This is an easy fix in your code; however I spotted several other problems:

1. Redundant code, like blocks and variables.
2. Pretty much an example of how to ***fail*** to follow the [**Single Responsibility Principle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).
3. You don't need a *"one or the other"* approach as other answers are showing. You can get ***both behaviors*** with a simple `boolean flag` acting as the switch.

Here some commented code accounting for all these things, provided in hopes you can learn-from-reference:

```
//Defines how to get and compare distance; used during sorting
public class DistanceComparer<T> : IComparer<T> where T : GameObject {
   public int Compare(T a, T b) {
       return Vector3.Distance(a.transform.position, b.transform.position);
   }
}

public var bool lockToTargetUntilDead = true; //Should lock to target till it's dead (true)? Or switch to nearest if the nearest changes (false)?

//Finds nearest enemy
GameObject FindNearestEnemy() {
    var enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(enemyTag);
    if (enemies==null || enemies.Length==0) return null; //No enemies anywhere
    Array.Sort(enemies, new DistanceComparer()); //Sort enemies by distance
    return enemies[0]; //Return closest enemy
}

//Determines if enemy is within range (Note: If enemy is null, it's not in range =P)
bool IsWithinRange(GameObject enemy) {
    return enemy != null && Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemy.transform.position) <= range;
}

//Updates target
void UpdateTarget() {
    var nearestEnemy = FindNearestEnemy();
    if(!IsWithinRange(nearestEnemy)) { //No enemies within range...
        if(target != null) target = null; //Forget current target.
        return; //Return-early.
    }
    if(lockToTargetUntilDead && target!=null) return; //If locking to current target and it ain't dead yet, return-early
    target = nearestEnemy; //If not locking to target, or doesn't have a target, new target!
}

void Start () {
    InvokeRepeating("UpdateTarget", 0f , 0.5f );
}
```

Comment: [Coroutines would be better than the heavy-overhead string-lookup Invoke](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/120554/75627).

Comment: @Draco18s Agreed. But at least so far, #NotMyProblem. I was more interested in providing more general code style improvement; I didn't really pay much attention to optimization issues in the original code, or improvements that could be done regarding those. --- +1 for the useful reference for the OP and future readers tho; and feel free to edit and add the optimization stuff if you feel like it (I don't, ATM).